# Bootstrap CSS breaking widget UI

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, widget

We have created a widget with Angular 4 which can be integrated with any website.
But if host website is using Bootstrap CSS, its breaking our widget UI.

When we build our widget in Angular 4 we get following files which we call in host `index.html`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>`

`<link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

For e.g host `index.html` looks like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ChatWidget</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
<!--other host website content-->

  <app-widget></app-widget>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="nline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

So my question is how can I prevent the Bootstrap CSS from interfering with my widget style.

Example of breaking UI

|
|
with Bootstrap

[image]

|
|
without Bootstrap

[image]

Comment: how is it breaking it? what is it doing? can you give us examples of what is going wrong?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Hi, I have added screen shots to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check the box-sizing property with and without bootstrap. It can be the case that bootstrap is overwriting the existing one.